# How to handle an error on a webpage selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written code that goes onto https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity.

I want to introduce another parameter in my code. So when i go onto the webpage and click the continue button without entering any data i get an validation error on the page 'Please provide your postcode, as different regions have different fuel prices.'

How can i introduce a check in my code so that it validates this message displayed is correct. I've tried to find an XPath but i'm not sure that is the right way to go about it

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class RunPath
    {

            static void Main()
            {

                IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity");
                webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this cssSelector

```
     div[class$='validation-error']
```

Looking fetching error message.

In Java+TestNG, usually will do assertions

```
  Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class$='validation-error']")).getText().trim(), "Please provide your postcode, as different regions have different fuel prices.");
```

Comment: OP is asking solution in C# Nuint , Not in JAVA and testng.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait for validation error element:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class RunPath
    {
            static void Main()
            {
                IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity");
                webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

                webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();

                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                IWebElement error = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'validation-error')]")));
                Assert.AreEqual("Please provide your postcode, as different regions have different fuel prices.", validationError.Text.TextTrim());
            }
    }           
}
```

Comment: I've got the first 2 lines of code to work. But the Assert is throwing up an error and validationError in the last line

Comment: @L.Dockster try again, answer was edited. If occur error give stacktrace

Comment: Still getting the same error with Assert.AreEqual and validationError

Comment: Did you change "Excpected validation error text" to "Please provide your postcode, as different regions have different fuel prices."?

Comment: @L.Dockster please check if your code is identical to my edited answer. give error message if you will get it

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on continue button, you can try this code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement error = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'validation-error')]")));
Assert.AreEqual("Please provide your postcode, as different regions have different fuel prices.", error.Text.TextTrim());
```