# Assert.AreEqual Issue with validation error c# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having issues with my `Assert.AreEqual` My code is validating whether an validation error I'm expecting is correct or not. But in my `Assert.AreEqual` and `validationError` are throwing up an exception.

You can see the validation error if you go onto https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity then click on the continue button without entering any information in any of the fields

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement error = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'validation-error')]")));

Assert.AreEqual("Excpected validation error text", validationError.TextTrim());




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class RunPath
    {

            static void Main()
            {

                IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity");
                webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();



            String title = webDriver.Title;

            String expectedTitle = "Utilities from Go Compare";
            if (title.Contains(expectedTitle))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tile is matching with expected value");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Title does not match");
            }


            String someText = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h1[@class='c-header__heading']")).Text;

            String expectedHeader = "Switch today and save on your energy bills";
            if (someText.Contains(expectedHeader))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("title matches");
            }
            else
            {

                throw new Exception("Title does not match");
            }


            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@type = 'submit']")).Click();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'validation-error')]")));

            Assert.AreEqual("Expected validation error text", validationError.TextTrim());
```

Comment: it's duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303774/how-to-handle-an-error-on-a-webpage-selenium-c-sharp

Comment: what error? give stacktrace, error message etc

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
Assert.AreEqual("Excpected validation error text", validationError.TextTrim());
```

try this :

```
IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'validation-error')]")));
Assert.AreEqual("Please provide your postcode, as different regions have different fuel prices.", country.Text.Trim());
```

**UPDATE :**

If you want to do it without Nunit. As per our discussion

You can follow these steps :

```
IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'validation-error')]")));  
String errorMsg = country.Text();
try{ 
if(errorMsg.Trim().Contains("Please provide your postcode, as different regions have different fuel prices."))
Console.WriteLine("Yes matched");
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine("Error msg did not match with the exact error msg");
}
```

Comment: I get the name 'Assert' doesn't existing in the current context  and IWebElement doesn't contain a definition for 'TextTrim'

Comment: @L.Dockster : Updated the whole answer , kindly check now.

Comment: Assert and wait does not exist in current context

Comment: Print this line :   Console.WriteLine(country.Text);

Comment: The issue is = wait and Assert are underlined in red

Comment: and this error is because of Nunit and Microsoft unit framework. It has nothing to do with the answer which I have provided. Are you even able to run your program ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174890/discussion-between-l-dockster-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: Updated the code though , in update section. Please have a look.